# Does any first-person video of a rocket launch exist?

Tags: launch, video

I'm trying to find a good depiction of what it looks like to pass out of the atmosphere and watch blue skies transition to a starfield.  What would be ideal is video looking out the window of a manned rocket launch, but I haven't been able to find any.  The closest I've found is [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zyq5eN9C4Cc) mounted on a rocket, but the camera was pointed down rather than outward, making it useless for my purposes.

Does anyone know if such a video exists, and if so, where I could find it?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Here ya go! It includes some other views, but does have the dashcam.

As usual though you can't really see the stars.

Shuttle mission STS-133

Comment: surprisingly unspectacular

Comment: Spectacles are to be avoided in rocketry. Just another routine launch to orbit.

Comment: I've asked a question about this video here: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/44089/what-are-the-things-that-blow-off-the-nose-of-the-space-shuttle-in-this-video-du

Comment: Guess we'll have to settle for CGI video :-)

Comment: Tangential question: where is this video *ORIGINALLY* available? It's NASA and should therefore be public domain, but the other watermark is obviously not NASA's and links to a site of questionable provenance, reputability, and functionality. Someone needs to get another copy of the original and post it.

Comment: @DoktorJ agreed. I was annoyed to see the advertising watermark as well. If you can locate the original, please edit it into the answer.  Unfortunately NASA has largely broken the formerly great resource for shuttle pix and video, spaceflight.nasa.gov If you click on the STS-133 video button, it takes you to a generic page!